# Cassandra Static Column design

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

How are static columns stored internally in cassandra?  Can someone please post an example discussing the design implementation of static column in cassandra?

Comment: I have already searched over the internet for the documentation but cant find any details related to internal structure

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why don't we take a look at the structure of a table with static columns on disk and find out?

```
cqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE test (k int, v int, s int static, d int, PRIMARY KEY(k,v))

cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO test (k, v, s, d) VALUES ( 1, 1 ,20, 1 );
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO test (k, v, s, d) VALUES ( 1, 3 ,21, 2 );
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO test (k, v, s, d) VALUES ( 1, 2 ,21, 2 );
```

Exit out of C* and run `nodetool flush` to make our sstables. Run `sstable2json` on the .db file that was created in the data directory.

```
[
{"key": "1", <--- K=1 Partition
 "cells": [[":s","21",1425050917842350], <---- Our Static Column
           ["1:","",1425050906896717], < --- C=1 row
           ["1:d","1",1425050906896717], < --- C=1, D=1 value
           ["2:","",1425050917842350], < --- C=2 row
           ["2:d","2",1425050917842350], < --- C=2, D=2 value
           ["3:","",1425050912874025], <--- C=3 Row
           ["3:d","2",1425050912874025]]} <--- C=3, D=2 Value
]
```

You can see that in Cassandra this static column is held in a cell with the title "Blank:ColumnName" at the very beginning of our partition. Unlike all the other cells there is no information about *c*(our clustering column) in the cell name, so all values of *c* will still modify the same static column *s*

For more details on why this is, check out the JIRA at
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6561
and the blog post at
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql-in-2-0-6